# Kotlin/Native, mem leak hunting when valgrind dumps core

Tags: valgrind, kotlin-native

Valgrind, under Ubuntu 18.04lts goes and dies in fire (dumps core to /dev/null) when I try find where and why my K/N (kotlin/Native) cmdline app leaks mem (due companion object toRegex() 's, but not sure...). Any idea how to proceed when a robust tool goes and dies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases pure Native programs without interop or atomic references shall not leak. Good approach is to create minimal reproducer and report to JetBrains using issue tracker. As Valgrind shall not crash as well, report to Valgrind devs may help as well.